# KendoUI grid - disable some filter operators per column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to disable (or maybe define some custom list of) operators per column.
I tried to do this in columns definitions:

```
"field": "Name",
"title": "name",
"attributes": {
    "class": "nameCell"
},
"filterable": {
    "operators": gridTranslationService.getHierarchyOperators()
}
```

But it not works for me. Any sugestions how can I do that ?

Comment: ok, but there is about default operator for cell, not list of operators for cell/column.

Comment: for example I have column named: "Status", and thid field is defined as type "string". Now I want to modify list of filters to only two positions: eq and neq. The question is : How can I do it only for this column, not for whole grid ?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set `status` column definition as:

```
    columns: [
      {
        field: "status",
        filterable: {
          operators: {
            string: {
              eq: "Equal to",
              neq: "Not equal to"
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
      { field: "id", filterable: false },
      {
        field: "status",
        filterable: {
          operators: {
            string: {
              eq: "Equal to",
              neq: "Not equal to"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    filterable: true,
    dataSource: [ 
      { status: "error", id: 1 }, 
      { status: "warning", id: 2 },
      { status: "warning", id: 3 },
      { status: "warning", id: 4 }
    ] 
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: My mistake is about defining firtelable in grid config object as object with translation to whole operators. Now If I had firtelable set to true everything working fine.

Comment: There is no `columns.filterable.operators` in Kendo's js api documentation on Grid's page. Is the documentation incomplete? How did you know that you could put `operators` inside `columns`?

Comment: @OnaBai's sample works fine for string-columns. If you have a number-column then you must write: operators: { number: { eq: "Equal to" } }. I found a blog post about this: http://brianseekford.com/wordpress/?p=675#comment-19726

Comment: How do I completely disable the filter?

Comment: @JamesWierzba you can set `filterable: false`